# Why Dataflow does not support SortByKey?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I was wondering why Dataflow does not support 'SortByKey' like Apache Spark.

I have a huge table in BigQuery that I cannot sort it because "Order By" is not scalable. So, I was thinking to move the output of BigQuery to Dataflow and sort it there. But, there is no SortByKey and it seems I have to write a combiner.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting (especially by key) requires globally serial processing, which is not a scalable operation. Apache Beam / Dataflow does not provide such support, as it is frequently unnecessary.

There are a variety of alternatives that generally address the need more scalably. For instance, you can sort the values within each key, which allows each key to be processed in parallel. Another common use case is TopN either globally or per-key. Again, this can be supported much more efficiently than actually sorting.

Could you elaborate on what you need to sort by and why? It would make it possible to identify options for implementing this within the Beam and Dataflow SDKs.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I have an unsorted VCF (Variant Call Format) file. KV<KV<chromosome ID, start>, object>>. It's a sparse matrix in my case. I tried to partition the table among several subqueries (e.g, per chromosome) but I preferred to avoid BigQuery due to its high cost. What do you suggest?

Comment: Can you update your question to explain what you need sorted and by what? Based on your description, it isn't clear what kind of sorting you need. For instance, it seems like you shouldn't need a global sort. If you changed that to a `KV<ChromosomeID, KV<Start, Object>>` and sorted the values by `Start` within each `ChromosomeID`, you wouldn't need a global sort -- just sorting within each key.

Comment: Sorry, sure. You can assume <chromosome, start> are the primary key.  Do you mean groupByKey <chromosome ID> and then sort based on start. But, I'm afraid each group may not fit into memory.

Comment: Yes. You can look at using the [SortValues](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/extensions/sorter/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sorter/SortValues.java) operation from the Apache Beam SDK (it should be compatible with Dataflow 2.0 and above which are based on Beam). This uses an external sorter to sort the values within a key by writing them to disk. I believe this should address your concerns about not fitting into memory.

Comment: Hi @Ben, is there any alternative to SortValues in Apache Beam Python?